# Xamarin.Forms Navigation

Tags: xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms

How can I find out if the current present page was pushed on the NavigationStack or on the ModalStack?
I want something like this:

```cs
bool isModal = CheckIsModalPage();
if(isModal)
    Navigation.PopModalAsync();
else
    Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Navigation` property of a `Page` does have a `ModalStack` property which should hold the pages that are currently presented modally, so you should be able to see if the current page is on that stack, e.g.:

```
if (Navigation.ModalStack.Contains(page))
    Navigation.PopModalAsync();
else
    Navigation.PopAsync();
```

See: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/modal/#Performing_Navigation

Comment: I had figured it out already, but thanks! The difference in my case is that I check it recursively, because sometimes this modal page was wrapped in a NavigationPage.